# Remote Desktop connection starts up, screen draws, then goes black

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop

Sometimes when I remote into my computer, I can get in and see everything and drive the mouse for a few seconds -- then the screen goes black and just sits there.

Anyone seen this before and know the reason or how to fix?

Answer (score 8):

I encountered very much alike problem few times. Finally, today I've found a [solution](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winserverTS/thread/31b681c5-3658-45a5-8158-a0a0f967c4a2) that worked for me:

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>End</kbd> (emulates Ctrl-Alt-Del in RDP session)
2. Hit **Cancel**.
3. Close and reopen RDP (maybe this step is not required). The screen will return.

In the worst case you can try to restart the remote machine.

Answer (score 3):

I've had this same problem where the login process is visible then suddenly goes black, and found the solution [here](http://www.adamjamesnaylor.com/2012/09/07/RDPBlackScreenAndTheChildishTechSupport.aspx). Simply disable "Bitmap caching" in the RDP session properties:

[image]

Comment: I could't comment previous post... It almost worked for me (using windows 7 both on client and server): I had to uncheck also 'visual style' in the experience tab of Remote Desktop Connection properties